$R$ direct sum of right minimal ideals; every right ideal is of the form $eR$ with $e$ idempotent

Let $R$ be a ring (with $1$) which is the direct sum of right minimal ideals. Show that every right ideal of $R$ is of the form $eR$ with $e$ idempotent.

$R={\oplus}_{1\geq k\geq n}I_k$; $1=i_1+i_2+ \dots+i_k$
$$i_1=i_1^2+i_2i_1+\dots+i_ki_1 \implies \underbrace{i_1-i_1^2}_{ \in I_1}=\underbrace{i_2i_1+\dots+i_ki_1}_{\in \sum_{j \neq 1}I_j} \implies i_1=i_1^2$$
$\rightarrow i_k=i_k^2;\; \forall k=1,\dots n$
Let $i:=i_j$ with $i_j\neq 0$, then $R=iR \oplus (1-i)R$
If $0 \neq I \triangleleft_{r} R$ minimal
Let $x \in I -\{0\}$ and suppose that $I^2 \neq \{0\}$.
Then, $xI \neq \{0\}$ for some $x \in I$ and as $xI \subseteq I$; $xI=I$:
$$(\ast)\; xe=x \implies x(e^2-e)=0 $$ for some $e \in I$.
Let $D:=\{a \in I \mid xa=0\} \triangleleft_{r} I$ and as $xI \neq \{0\}; D=\{0\}$ as $I$ is minimal.
And now we have that $e^2=e; e \neq 0  \;(\ast)$  and $eR=I$.
Which approach should be considered for other cases?

@JP Is it the case you do not yet have any theory about semisimple modules? Is this part of learning that theory?

I haven't got any sufficient module theory, I'm sorry

Rather than considering multiple cases (which sounds a bit messy), I think it would be most fruitful to first show that

Let $M$ be a right $R$ module that is a direct sum of simple submodules. Then every submodule of $M$ is a direct summand of $M$.  (Proven here)

Taking $M_R=R_R$ as a special case, all that remains is to show summands of $R_R$ are of the form $eR$ for some idempotent $e$, which is the subject of
this post.
Or, if you already know that if every summand $N$ of $M$ is given by $e(M)$ where $e$ is an idempotent element of $End(M_R)$, and that $End(R_R)\cong R$, you could also go that route.
